# Ubuntu 16.04 fresh install freezes on boot

Tags: boot, nvidia

Live version works, installation does not work at all (zero times).

During boot there is a blinking cursor, and nothing else. The cursor changes lines twice and then does nothing.

I tried to enter "recovery mode" by holding shift but could not get into it.

I have AMD processor and an NVIDIA geforce gtx 960 graphics card.

EDIT:
I tried acpi = off , nolapic , nomodset by booting from the stick, pressing down arrow, then f6, setting those options and then "boot from first hard disk". Now I get "Boot failed: press a key to retry..."

I tried setting "Boot failure guard" disabled from bios. Still doesn't work.

edit2: After using 16.04 network installer, it now proceeded from the blinking cursor to a black screen, after pressing alt + arrows it now says: "/dev/sbd1: clean, 5741/3139584 files, 518152/12556544 blocks", then alt arrowing got me to a text login ... and now I don't seem to have a graphical UI, I'm in the text terminal. Apparently I should've known to tick the right boxes when it asked what to update?
edit3: installed the whole piece of crap again since I'm tired finding out about archive mirrors and their failures.

It seems to work now with the GUI.

The network installer asked me to confirm installing GRUB boot loader to the booting hard drive, unlike the normal installer, maybe that is why it works now?

Comment: Have you installed in UEFI mode?

Comment: Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) answer.

Comment: The live cd (or stick) works. I just cannot boot from my hard drive.

Comment: I cannot get to the GRUB menu by holding right shift. Nothing happens and it freezes as described above.

Comment: I tried acpi = off , nolapic , nomodset by booting from the stick, pressing down arrow, then f6, setting those options and then "boot from first hard disk". Now I get "Boot failed: press a key to retry..."

Comment: Regarding UEFI, I don't know if I have it. I disabled "secure boot" from my BIOS, it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

The network installer asked me to confirm installing GRUB boot loader to the booting hard drive, unlike the normal installer, maybe that is why it works now?

Tbh I'm very tired already of this software. It should not make me waste so many hours when I just want to run some programs on it.